# How to send PDF file to express node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

In my react component's render method return I have a file input

```
input required type="file" name="file" id="file" onChange={fileUploader} className="form-control" />
```

outside the return, still in the render method (just for testing), I have the function that converts the file to an Array buffer and calls the sending http helper function function

```
const fileUploader = (e) => {

            var reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = e => {

                sendPDF(reader.result);
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0])
    };
```

I am then sending a fetch post request with the array buffer as the body and headers.content-type as text/plain.

on the Node Express side req.body is empty.

but in the network tab, I see the request payload binary data.

Comment: What body parser middlewares do you have?

Comment: Nothing, I'm just trying to send the pdf file as a post. I'm not using a middleware. Am I missing something? I thought I could just send the arraybuffer, get it on the node side so that I can then use pdf2json.

Comment: `req.body` only exists if a body parser middleware creates it.

Comment: Are you not using jQuery?

Comment: @Md.SharifulIslam no just using fetch

Comment: @SLaks I am creating it myself. In the config of the fetch, I am assigning the arrayBuffer to the body `let fetchRequestInfo = {
        method: 'post',
        headers: headers,
        body: payload
    };`

Comment: why do you need to convert the file? just send the the data as multipart content type. whole file will be posted on server